# execute permission for a dictionary

Tags: linux, permissions

If I grant execute permission to all users (who are not owner, and not same group user, --x in this case), here is an example below, I want to confirm my understanding is correct -- it means anyone could cd to the dictionary, but cannot using command like "ls" to list content of the dictionary? I am using CentOS Linux.

```
drwxrwx--x 4 root root    4096 Feb 27 15:02 .
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The letters rwxXst select file mode bits for the affected users: read
>   (r), write (w), **execute (or search for directories) (x)**

[man chmod](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod)

Your understanding is nearly correct, but the `x`-flag is generally not about listing files but about **executing** them. If you set `+x` for directories, you can search them (`find`, `ls` etc.), but **not** read the actual contents of the files.

Comment: Thanks Thor77, if I want user to be able to enter the dictionary (using cd command) and execute one of the binary files under the dictionary, but do not want them to list all files under the dictionary, I think I should set all other users --x permission for the dictionary as I did?

Comment: @LinMa No, you have to set '--x' for all **files inside** the folder, but not **on** the folder, because then users can search the folder (`find`, `ls`, etc.)

Comment: Thanks Thor77, I am a bit confused, I just need the user to enter directory and execute one of the binary files under the directory. Why I need to set '--x' for all files?

Comment: @LinMa you just have to set `+x` on the binary files. `+x` has a different behaviour on folders and files (as already mentioned in my answer).

Comment: Thanks Thor77, do you mean I just set +x on binary file and they can execute from absolute path of the directory, without entering (cd command) the directory? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa For your unix-system it's no difference if you enter the directory and run `./binfile` or directly `./path/to/dir/binfile`

Comment: Thanks Thor77, I want to confirm my understanding is correct, if I do not grant +x on the directory level, the user cannot cd into the directory, and have to execute by using the full path, correct?

Comment: @LinMa The user can `cd` into the directory (not sure though, just try it) but can't run `ls`

Comment: Thanks Thor77, vote up. Always good to learn from you. Then "cd" requires what kinds of permission, if it is not +x? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa My assumption was wrong, you need `+x` access to the directory with your bin-files to access (read, write, execute) them: [Screencast](https://asciinema.org/a/5pn1etszat4jwl21hv89hqbr5)

Comment: Thanks Thor77, let me final confirm the right steps since I do not want to open unnecessary permissions. :)

I need to +x for both folder and the binary file (no need to +r for them). And also in this way, the other users could execute by absolute path to the binary file, saying /path/to/bin/files/binary? Thanks.

Comment: Yep, you need to set `+x` on both the folder and the binary file. But `+r` is also required (how is your system supposed to read the binary-data to execute it otherwise?). If you set `+r` for `others` on the folder + the bin-file `others` can also execute it by absolute path (same goes for `group`. As mentioned above, that's no difference for your system.

Comment: BTW, Thor77, I tried only +x needed on folder, for binary file, no need for +r for other users to execute. Maybe I am wrong? Appreciate if you could help to confirm as well. :)

Comment: @LinMa You're wrong. Every "section" (`owner`, `group`, `other`) needs `+rx` to execute a file, because reasons mentioned above. (Consider reading [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/how-do-directory-permissions-in-linux-work) answer about directory-specific rights). Also, please consider moving this discussion into chat because your further questions are not really related to the original one.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, Thor77. Mark your reply as an answer. :)